# Django - Model Helper Property for current user

Tags: django, django-models

I'm looking for a way to get an object filtered with the current logged in user from a *model helper property*

Let me give an example

```
class Exo(models.Model):
  """Exercises"""
  text = models.TextField()

class Score(models.Model):
  """Scores of users by exercise"""
  exo = models.ForeignKey(Exo)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  score = models.IntegerField()
  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('exo', 'user',),)
```

From the model `Exo` I'd like to be able to get the score of the logged in user

```
class Exo(models.Model):
  """Exercises"""
  text = models.TextField()
  def get_logged_score():
    return self.score_set.filter(user=current_logged_user)[0]
```

From the `Exo` object, how can I get the score of the `current_logged_user` ?

**Edit**: The idea is to use `get_logged_score` from a template, so I can't pass any parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By passing it in.

```
def get_logged_score(self, user):
   ...
```

Comment: This idea is to use it from a template, so I can't pass any parameter. Will I be forced to use a template tag ?

Comment: Yes, or do the query in your view.

Comment: Ok I think it's better to do the query in the view, I'm going to post a new question to know how I can put the scores in the same list of object :)